# Performance Test - Distributed mode with jtl and smtp listener

Tags: jmeter

My test consists of tear down thread that sends the JTL report in the email through SMTP listener. This works fine when I run the tests in non distributed model as the JTL file is in one machine.
The issue I am facing is when I run these tests in distributed mode ( for some heavy loads). SMTP listener fails as the file is not found in the slave where the tests are running since JTL file is in the master. is there anyway I can make this work within the JMeter tests or do I need to create a separate script once the test is done to send the final report through email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option would be indeed creating a separate test script for sending the results.

Alternative option would be

1. kicking off another JMeter Slave instance at the same host with the master
2. Limiting the SMTP Sampler to be executed only on that host via [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) and [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) functions combination like this:

   [image]

This way you will be able to run SMTP Sampler only on the machine where the .jtl file lives.